# How to calculate FPS over timespan per second for mobile game?

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, performance-testing, frame-rate

I am testing game, developed in Unity. I need to calculate frames per second over timespan. I do not have source code, so not able to add any UI decorators in unity. I have only apk, which i install on my phone. I CAN NOT use Gamebench. But idea to have something as Gamebench. 
I tried so far, but not very useful: 
   adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger

Please, any ideas?

Comment: i assume calculation should be: 
timespan = realtimeSinceStart - LastTime
frameCount = frameCount - lastFrameCount
current FPS = frameCount/timespan

But, how can i use it in the program?

Comment: Hey there! Any reason why you can't use GameBench?

Disclaimer: I'm a senior engineer at GameBench